# Emitted jsonmessage from Unity to nodejs using Unity-socketio-websocketsharp can not be parsed

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, websocket-sharp

I try to send a json message using the emit method from the `unitysocketio-websocketsharp` library but the received message can not be parsed.

```
socket.Emit("data", "{\"name\":\"data\",\"args\":[{\"name\":\"testvariable1\",\"value\":\"-63\"}]}");
```

The connection can be build up and I can also receive messages from `nodejs`.

The debug output from nodejs looks like this where the [args] argument stays empty:

"name":"testvariable1","value":-63
  debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"data","args":[{}]}

Comment: You are sending the negative value as a String. Are you prepared for that on the receiving side? Also, if you send a simple json, does the parsing work?

Comment: Yes the receiving side can work with negative values. What exactly do you mean with a simple json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i got it working not with the emit method but with the send method:

```
EventMessage evm = new EventMessage();
evm.Event = "data";
evm.MessageText = "{\"name\":\"data\",\"args\":[{\"name\":\"testvariable1\",\"value\": -63}]}";
socket.Send(evm);
```